# How can I save a html file with external resources using AFNetworking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, afnetworking

I would like to save a .html webpage with AFNetworking, but would also like to save the resources (such as .css files, .js files, images etc) within the webpage so that the whole webpage can be viewed offline.

Is this possible with AFNetworking, and how would I do it? Could a short example be posted please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFNetworking is not necessary to do this. Instead, what you want to do is use an `NSURLCache` subclass that supports disk cacheing (such as [Peter Steinberger's fork of SDURLCache](https://github.com/steipete/SDURLCache)). With that in place, just load up a URL using a `UIWebView` (this may not necessarily have to be displayed to a user), and subsequent loads should use that local cache.

At the very least, do not waste your time trying to write something on your own to download assets on a webpage. This process *requires* a web browser (which `UIWebView` qualifies as) to determine everything needed to load.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer! I've imported the files for SDURLCache, but would I be able to have some short sample code on how to save the url with resources with SDURLCache? :-)